# How do I say a thing that I know but not sure understand clearly

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm going to describe a definition to team members that most of them may know it, but they probably don't understand much. So, is there any good English words to say a thing that is:

- easy to hear and know it
- hard to understand to the edge
- pretty confused

For example:
"Have you ever known about the X? That's one of the most `suggest word` term in our working methodology."

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

[Abstract](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/abstract)

> Have you ever known about X? That is one of the most abstract terms in our working methodology. You have probably seen or used the method without knowing the name of it or what it is in essence...